# Delegate persisted objects to Redis, with MySQL fallback

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had this idea, and I want to run it by some people knowledgable about Redis and/or MySQL, so that you can tell me that I'm stupid for even considering this.

I'm wondering what the implications would be of storing persisted objects in Redis for reading, with a fallback to the database data should the Redis key not exist. For the sake of brevity, here is a (very) simple example of what I have in mind:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.cache_or_query(id)
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{self.name}:#{id}") || begin
      record = self.find(id)
      Rails.cache.write("#{record.class}:#{record.id}", record)
      record
    end
  end
end

person = Person.create(name: "Tom Hanks", email: "thanks@gmail.com")
Person.cache_or_query(person.id) #=> query database, cache gets written, get Person object
Person.cache_or_query(person.id) #=> query Redis, get Person object
```

And then in the CMS, saving a record would simply expire its cache (or perhaps overwrite it with the new data).

So, my question is: Given decent server conditions, could Redis out-perform MySQL (or any database)? My goal is to cut down on the number of SQL queries being performed on every page, and my hope is that I could delegate to Redis, which I believe to be faster at retrieving data. I will be benchmarking this regardless of responses, but I'm curious to hear other's opinions anyways, and more importantly, what about this setup would completely fail on a high-activity website in production.

I admittedly am not an expert on the internals of MySQL or Redis, so I hope to get some insightful answers.

Thanks!

**Update** The results of the Benchmark are that it seems to be a negligible performance increase: Less than 1 second per 10,000 queries: https://gist.github.com/3844026

Is it worth it?

Comment: I know that this question might not be appropriate for SO, as it's more of a discussion. If someone could point me to the proper place to post something like this, I'll be happy to close this thread and move it there.

Comment: Basically, `isItWorthIt = (time it takes to process mysql query + round trip time to reach mysql instance) > (time it takes to process redis command + round trip time to reach redis instance)`; redis is speedy, but since on the same network the round trip time is going to be pretty much constant no matter whether you hit redis or mysql, if the query on mysql was already performing fast you won't see much of a difference, and if it wasn't, you would usually just cache the results.

Comment: maybe you could use such a thing as airbag in a mysql crash or maintenance reboot. But not to speeding things (as you already know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL already has its working set in memory. And you are not getting anything from Redis when you do complex selects with filters etc. You are just going to use redis for single objects.

Moreover, ActiveRecord already caches associations on existing objects....

It's totally not worth it.

Comment: You're right - complex queries would be a burden, I'd have to practically write a new adapter, for a negligible performance boost. Thanks for the input!